# Extracting some string between two symbols

Tags: regex, postgresql

i have example data that looks like this... here is one instance

```
some data information: (sometext:1234:2022-1-1)
```

I would like to extract the string between the parenthesis so the data would look something like this

```
(sometext:1234:2022-1-1)
```

having some trouble with regular expressions so help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you show your attempt at using postgres regular expression that you're having trouble with, please?

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will achieve this:  `\([^)]+\)`

Which is: a `(` followed by at least one character that is not a `)` followed by `)`. As the parentheses `()` are used for grouping they have to be escaped at the beginning and the end.

This regex can be used with the `substring()` function:

```
select substring('some data information: (sometext:1234:2022-1-1)' from '\([^)]+\)')
```

Comment: I would add left bracket to the character class.